# backporting NSWindowDelegates windowDidEndLiveResize behaviour in OSX 10.5?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

While 10.6 introduced the neat `- windowDidEndLiveResize:` et al for `NSWindowDelegate`, i need similar behaviour in 10.5 to avoid constantly invoking heavier functions via `- windowDidResize:`.
Currently i can only think of a timer-based solution (i.e. checking in short intervals for when the last resize occured), which seems ugly.

Is there a better way to support that? Or at least a way to get the specific mouse-down/-up events on the resize control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try querying the `inLiveResize` method from the content view of the window. When the window is resized, its content view is resized as well.

Comment: Ah, views already had events like `viewDidEndLiveResize` since 10.1 - thank you.